# CSS Marquee: multiple paragraphs overlaps

Tags: html, css, marquee

I'm working on this simple marquee effect for the mobile version of a site, my problem is, all the paragraphs overlaps.

I just want to see it, one by one then repeat.

hope you can help me.

Thanks.

**HTML**

```
<div class="marquee">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            <p>quis rem exercitationem perspiciatis ducimus repellat dicta sapiente totam aperiam repellendus eos libero.</p>
            <p>Placeat hic magnam nostrum sit tempore labore ipsa rerum</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
    .marquee {
        width: 100%;
  height:30px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.marquee p {
    position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  font-size:13px;
  line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  /* Starting position */

  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
  /* Apply animation to this element */

  -moz-animation: scroll-left 30s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: scroll-left 30s linear infinite;
  animation: scroll-left 30s linear infinite;
}
```

Sorry I cut the css code, its too long, cant submit.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Leoxw9u/)

Answer (score 2):

Check this : https://jsfiddle.net/Lxp983mt/2/

i added an `animation-delay` to your `p` elements individually and changed the styling  (you will find a comment above any change)

> note : if you want to increase the `animation-duration` you will have to play with `animation-duration` values on your `p` elements

Answer (score 1):

instead of using separate tag place contents in a single paragraph tag.

```
   <div class="marquee">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. quis rem exercitationem perspiciatis ducimus repellat dicta sapiente totam aperiam repellendus eos libero. Placeat hic magnam nostrum sit tempore labore ipsa rerum</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: that's my last choice actually.

Comment: Use a separate Marquee div tag for all the paragraph that would get you in separate lines if that's your requirement. If you need in same line it would work in the way you posted unless we have marquee tag separately for each paragraph and delay them to display in one by one.

Comment: I see, about your answer , the problem is it took time to show the text. https://jsfiddle.net/5Lmwf3jr/